# c++ : passing ofstream& to function to continually append to .txt file

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, fstream, ofstream

I am writing a program for class wherein I need to call a function multiple times from "main.cpp" which takes an ofstream as a parameter, and the function itself needs to append new data to the end of the .txt file every time it's called (in this example I've made the data of type int for simplicity's sake).

What's been happening is that when the function gets called multiple times in main, it just overwrites everything instead of appending new data to the end of the file. I know everything else in my program works so I'm just going to strip it down to the bare bones as much as possible so that this isn't TL;DR. I have included

```
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
```

in all of my files.

Here's the gist of it:

in main.cpp:

```
aClass* someClass = new aClass;
int data = 0;
...
ofstream myfile ("file.txt");
someClass->appendData(myfile, data);
...
```

in aClass.h:

```
void appendData(ofstream& myfile, int data);
```

in aClass.cpp:

```
void aClass::appendData(ofstream& myfile, int data){
    if(myfile.is_open()){
        myfile << data << "\n";
        myfile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Couldn't open file";
}
```

If anyone could help me with this I'd appreciate it. For some reason they haven't had us touch fstreams in over a year and I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: Why are you calling `myfile.close()` in `appendData`?

Comment: @RSahu I didn't know I shouldn't, they never showed us how to do this. Should I do that right before main exits instead? I didn't know it was okay to leave it open between stack frames

Comment: Remove it from `appendData`. Calling `myfile.close()` is `main` is optional. The destructor will call `close()`. However, there is no harm if you call `close()` on the object if you are sure you are not going to use it to write into it any more.

Comment: @RSahu thank you so much

Comment: `ofstream myfile ("file.txt");` means it will overwrite the old contents of `file.txt` . It's not clear from your question whether you are calling this multiple times in your program or not. You can append by using the open flag `std::ios::app`

Answer (score 1):

The call

```
myfile.close();
```

in `appendData` is not right. Any subsequent output operations on `myfile` are ignored.

Remove it from there.

You may add it in `main` but it is optional. The destructor will call `close()`. However, there is no harm if you call `close()` on the object if you are sure you are not going to use it to write into it any more

Comment: Are subsequent operations ignored, or are UB?

Comment: @GauravSehgal, It's ignored. Every output function construct and checks a sentry object. If the sentry object indicates the stream cannot be written into, nothing is done. An example is shown at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/sentry.